# NppExec won't take function for path in Notepad++

Tags: mingw, notepad++, nppexec

I wanted to be able to compile and run **C** and **C++** code from **Notepad++** on my flash drive (Using **PortableApps.com**). I got **MinGW** and put it on my flash drive, I adjusted [This Guy's](http://daleswanson.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-compile-c-code-in-notepad-with.html) **NppExec** script to work with a flash drive and it would work flawlessly except I don't always know what drive letter my flash drive is going to get.

When I pass it `%CD:~0,2%` it takes it as a string instead of a command. So the command:

```
cd %CD:~0,2%\MinGW\bin\
```

is attempted exactly as written. It doesn't try to convert the `%CD:~0,2%` into the drive letter. So if someone could help me figure out a way to better get the drive letter that would be nice.

Also, the reason I'm not just adding `MinGW\bin\` to the system variables is because my school's computer's have security software that would prevent me doing so. And I would still need the drive letter.

My assumption, as to the reasoning for my problem, is that **NppExec** doesn't know what to do with the `%` signs. So if someone knows a way around this...?

Here is the full code:

```
npp_save
cd %CD:~0,2%\MinGW\bin\
g++ "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O2
cmd /c move /Y $(NAME_PART).exe $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe
NPP_RUN $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe
```

The Output shows **NppExec** clearly disregarding my change directory command.
Here is the output:

```
NPP_SAVE: G:\Documents\ColumbiaCollege\C++CmpSc27\Assigns\Assign02-PRSA\JesseM_Assign02_RPS_Game.c
CD: %CD:~0,2%\MinGW\bin\
Current directory: G:\Documents\ColumbiaCollege\C++CmpSc27\Assigns\Assign02-PRSA
g++ "G:\Documents\ColumbiaCollege\C++CmpSc27\Assigns\Assign02-PRSA\JesseM_Assign02_RPS_Game.c" -o JesseM_Assign02_RPS_Game -march=native -O2
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.

cmd /c move /Y JesseM_Assign02_RPS_Game.exe G:\Documents\ColumbiaCollege\C++CmpSc27\Assigns\Assign02-PRSA\JesseM_Assign02_RPS_Game.exe
Process started >>>
The system cannot find the file specified.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
NPP_RUN: G:\Documents\ColumbiaCollege\C++CmpSc27\Assigns\Assign02-PRSA\JesseM_Assign02_RPS_Game.exe
- the specified file was not found
================ READY ================
```

Comment: What a warm welcome to SO, thanks. Look, I've spent several hours researching this, and trying to figure this out. Getting nowhere I might add. Even after I posted this question, I'm still working on it. I have no intention of abusing the knowledge in this community. I greatly respect Stack Overflow, considering most problems I've had, have been already asked and I never needed to make an account. You're implication that I immediately gave up and came on here is rather insulting.

Comment: Don't worry, that's a perfectly good question, IMHO. SO is great in general, but there are always members who will frustrate you with their negative attitude. That's life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the batch `set` command to put the drive letter into an environment variable, then use that variable in the NppExec script. To set the environment variable try something like:

```
set TheDriveLetter=%CD:~0,2%
```

To use it in the script use:

```
cd $(SYS.TheDriveLetter)\MinGW\bin\
```

There is more information in the section on variables in the [NppExec documentation](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~aedv/Notepad++Portable/App/Notepad++_ansi/plugins/doc/NppExec_Manual.txt).

Notepad++ may itself have some environment variables that provide the drive more easily. You could try [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Defining_User_Commands) for a list of them.

Comment: Thank you, It works. I love you. Could you further explain what this does and why it must be done this way?

Comment: @PastTheFuture I am not sure it _must_ be done that way, there are probably several other ways. I just looked at the user documentation for NppExec, searched for "variables" and wrote up my findings. NppExec has a limited command language, a bit like the Windows batch language but not as powerful. I saw a two step method to provide your answer, first get the drive letter, second use in it a NppExec command.